# Zero Knowledge Discrete Logarithm on Elliptic Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm, fiat-shamir

Can the [Discrete Logarithm ZK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_heuristic) be implemented on elliptic curves? It seems that such an implementation should look like the following:

1. $Y = \alpha G$
2. Random pick $v$
3. $t = vG$
4. $c = H(G, y, t)$
5. $r = v - cx$
6. Check: $t = rG + cY$

If yes, can I use ed25519 for this purpose and how can I select $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this non-interactive zero-knowledge proof works perfectly fine (with a suitable hash function) for proving knowledge of a discrete logarithm over e.g. ed25519. The basis $G$ is part of the statement: the statement is of the form "I know $\alpha$ such that $Y = G^\alpha$. As such, it works for any generator $G$ of your choice (which, over ed25519, is any element of the prime order subgroup except $0$, since its a prime order cyclic group).

Comment: Great! Thank you! But why G can be any element? As far as I know not all elements of a cyclic group are the generators

Comment: You are right sorry, I typed too fast - I meant, since ed25519 is a *prime order* cyclic group, all its elements (beyond the neutral element, i.e., $g^0$) are generators.

Comment: I think you need to be more careful about the claim that $G$ can be any element on the elliptic curve. The full group of elliptic curve points does not have prime order; it has a small cofactor. So, not every non-identity element is a generator. But every non-identity element of the large prime-order subgroup generates that subgroup.

Comment: Something like the [Ristretto group](https://ristretto.group/) solves that issue, or you could take the [standardized Ed25519 basepoint](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27392/base-point-in-ed25519).

Comment: Fixed the confusing statement, hopefully - I had the prime order subgroup in mind when saying "the elliptic curve", which of course is incorrect.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau  Thank you very much!!