# They key size of the Schnorr Signature Algorithm

Tags: public-key, discrete-logarithm, key-size, key-generation, schnorr-signature

Based on the Schnorr signature below: What is the suitable size of lamda to generate a secure key?

[image: Schnorr signature]

Comment: Since $\lambda$ appears only in $1^\lambda$ on input of key generation, and no relation is formally defined between that and $q$, that $1^\lambda$ mention in the quote is merely a display of technical jargon, and the question is not answerable in the exact form it's asked. Also, a stretch of imagination is required to see [the 1989 Schnorr signature scheme](https://schnorrsig.grieu.fr) ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00196725)). In particular, in the original, the hash is to a set of size $≈\sqrt q$, smaller than $\mathbb Z_q$ . [Related answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/92161/555).